# Always Encrypted Keys is missing in my SQL Server 2016 RC1

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I heard  Always Encrypted Keys is one of the great feature in SQL Server 2016. I have installed SQL Server 2016, but I could not find any folder like that in my Database folders. Can anyone please help me to find out what I missed? Thanks in advance. [image] . [image: SQL Server RC1]

Comment: Two things that spring to mind are: what version of SSMS are you using and what is the compatibility level of the database?

Comment: @BenThul Thanks, I am using SSMS 2016 version. Can you please explain what do you mean by compatibility level of database?

Comment: Run the ff query: `select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'ShibeeshPassion'`. You'd need the value to be 130. Per Ed Harper's observation below, the entire server that you're connected to is a SQL 2014 instance, so the Always Encrypted feature won't work.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks again, I run the query, it returns nothing. And how can I change my SQL instance from 2014 to 2016? It seems I have both in my system.

Comment: I took the name of the database from your screenshot - if it's different you'll need to change the name of the database in the query. You can either upgrade that 2014 instance using the 2016 installer it connect to the 2016 instance you already have. Run the configuration utility for an easy way to see all the instances in your machine.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks much, It seems I have done everything right. But I am not sure why my SSMS 2016 is connecting to SQL server 2014. Any quick things I should check with?

Comment: Because the management tools and the database server don't need to be the same version. That is, you can connect to a 2014 server with the 2016 SSMS. That's normal, in fact for the server and told to be different. You just need to put that in as the server name when asked what server you want to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself. I just uninstalled my SQL Server 2014 and then installed SQL Server 2016. Now I am able to see the Always Encrypted Keys option and other features as well. Thanks for all the help.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sibeesh, could you mark this response as the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot shows you are connected to a SQL Server 2014 instance (version number 12.0.4100). SQL Server 2016 has a version number 13.*n*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Previously I had 2014 version. Then I installed 2016 versions for both sql server and SSMS. Do I need to disable or Uninstaller 2014?

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have already installed SQL server 2016.